# Setting RTL or LTR style for text automatically based on text language

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a popup component in my Angular2 project. This popup acts as an error notification component and can have English or Persian messages. I want to set css style (LTR / RTL) based on the text language it's showing. The following is my component:

```
<dx-popup [rtlEnabled]="true" title="خطا" [(visible)]="errorPopupVisible" width="500" maxHeight="350" height="200" [shading]="true" shadingColor="rgb(0,0,0,0.5)"
    contentTemplate="popup-content" [wrapperAttr]="{id: 'errorPopup'}">
    <div *dxTemplate="let data of 'popup-content'">
        <p>{{errorMessage}}</p>
    </div>
</dx-popup>
```

How can I achieve this in my Angular project?